# After Upgrade To JRuby 9.1.9.0, Rails CookieStore Very Slow When Handling Encrypted Cookies

Tags: performance, ruby-on-rails-4, jruby

I recently upgraded a JRuby 1.7.x based Rails 4.2.5 Web application to JRuby 9.1.9.0.   When I deploy the to a web server,  page loads take up to 60sec.   I profiled the code and the bulk of the time is being spentt in the ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore call method.   I suspect this bottlenect is potentially related to jopenssl gem's encrypt/decrypt being slow but I have not found any help articles or solutions online.

Any insight into this issue,  possible options to configure JRuby would be appreciated.  The issue did not occur in JRuby 1.7.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**export JRUBY_OPTS=-J-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom** should do it

(or a jruby-openssl upgrade to 0.9.21)

Comment: thanks this worked.   any chance you could let me know why this wasn't an issue in JRuby 1.7.27?

Comment: you can deduce based on the answer - different (default) jruby-openssl version.