# Upgrading from jruby-9.0.5.0 hangs tomcat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tomcat, jruby

I am trying to upgrade jruby. Went to a latest version 9.1.12.0, didn't work. Tried one version up (9.1.0.0) and same issue

The issue is it takes a very long time to boot on tomcat. Once tomcat starts the application it becomes unresponsive. Browser hangs forever and then eventually times out. Tomcat log shows that the request came, was served reply and closed (everything normal). No errors show up in tomcat log.

Tomcat is sitting behind apache, connected though AJP. I tried switching to http(s) and neither worked. Going directly to tomcat yields the same results.

I worked on solving this issue for quite some time. Not sure why it hangs and doens't throw any errors. Tried changing configurations on rails/tomcat/apache and could not find why it doens't work.

Any help tracking down this issue would be greatly appreciated

Current stack:

- Rails 4.1..15
- Jruby 9.0.5.0
- Tomcat 6
- Java 1.7.0_131
- Apache 2.4.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like an enthropy depletion might be going on,

`export JRUBY_OPTS=-J-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom`

or in your case :

`export CATALINA_OPTS=-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom`

explanation is this' questions answer: [After Upgrade To JRuby 9.1.9.0, Rails CookieStore Very Slow When Handling Encrypted Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45111894/after-upgrade-to-jruby-9-1-9-0-rails-cookiestore-very-slow-when-handling-encryp)

... the next jruby-openssl release should hopefully handle this better

Comment: Thank you @kares! What is `/./` is for? Can it be just `/dev/urandom`?